# Converting a project from Python2 to Python3, strange error deep in a module now (astropy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, astropy

I had this project running on my Mac here under python3.   It took a while after doing a 2to3 to update some other bits and pieces to it to finally get it to run.  Now though the project fails and all I recall of doing to my mac is:
Upgrading the OS
Upgrading Xcode and other pieces so that a 'brew install root' would work.
Not sure what else it touched but it is like it lost all the modules I had done a pip install on.  So i redid a pip install on several modules

astropy
matplotlib
scipy

now the project fails when I run it:

```
  File "/Users/shathoma/TUI3/TUI/Guide/GuideImage.py", line 26, in <module>
    import astropy.io.fits as pyfits
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from . import convenience
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/convenience.py", line 63, in <module>
    from .diff import FITSDiff, HDUDiff
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/diff.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .header import Header
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/header.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .file import _File
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/io/fits/file.py", line 29, in <module>
    from astropy.utils.compat.optional_deps import HAS_BZ2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/utils/compat/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .numpycompat import *  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/utils/compat/numpycompat.py", line 14, in <module>
    NUMPY_LT_1_19 = not minversion('numpy', '1.19')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/utils/decorators.py", line 546, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/utils/introspection.py", line 167, in minversion
    return Version(module_version) >= Version(version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 264, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I have this project running fine still under a windows machine and the versions of the installed modules like astropy etc are the same.  Still fails on the mac with the above error.  I could go in and fix packaging/version.py to deal with a `self._regex.search(str(version))` which is a bad Idea I know (I tried that and since reverted it gave an error on how version = none somewhere.

it is almost like I am missing a module but nothing knows it?  Not sure, and not sure how after working this broke with just probably the brew install command of the root (https://root.cern.ch/) package. Out of ideas what to look for or try next to get this running again?

Comment: This sounds like just an installation problem, probably with your NumPy install. Do you know how to use pdb?

Comment: I have never heard of PDB is it a virtual environment?  I was specifically avoiding conda since I don't own this codebase and am just trying to port it we saw issues with running the program we have in conda that I have no way to fix and wasn't sure what was causing it.  Still not sure what caused this to begin with it was working until that brew install.  Numpy version same as on my windows machine which is working with the python 3 conversion of the software.

Comment: ahh it is a debugger, when the app crashes I see the stack trace and on code I wrote it crashes on an import... import astropy.io.fits as pyfits

Comment: That's mostly a coincidence.  The problem would occur in many other places where it's trying to check your NumPy version, which is probably broken due to a broken NumPy installation.  You can use pdb to inspect the local variables in the frames where the exception is occurring.  E.g. in an interactive prompt `import pdb; import astropy.io.fits; pdb.pm()`.  Then y ou can print the value of `version`.  Most likely it's something like `None`.  Or even directly try `from importlib import metadata; metadata.version('numpy')` and see what comes up.

Comment: You are right numpy is indeed a version of 'None', I checked scipy for sanity with that metadata.version('scipy') and got back 1.8.0, so numpy I guess is broke but not sure how to fix it?

Comment: I tried a pip3 uninstall numpy, and then did a pip3 install numpy and it used the cached version and I still get the same error then...

Comment: Many possible issues--wrong pip, wrong import paths, etc. I think it's something that would be hard to debug without looking at it directly.  I would suggest finding a local expert who can help, because it really sounds like a problem with your system.

Comment: ahh okay, I thought it was more of a simple delete folders xyz type of fix.  I can probably reload the OS or do something similar it is a mac os based system.  Ty for the insights though!

Comment: I guess by now this problem has been solved, but when I try to solve problems with installed packages, sometimes `python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir numpy` helps. That will ensure you install for the Python command you use (so no mismatch with a different pip. I've used `python3` explicitly here, to avoid a potential Python 2; you could even use `python3.9`); it will force a re-install, and ignore the cache.

Comment: I will have to try this, it was never resolved and I moved to a M1 mac min i and got everything working, but I need to be able to fix this going forward for any instance of anything so this is helpful for me to try since my macbook pro is still messed up.